# How to limit the results of codepen rss feed

Tags: javascript, rss

I am working on my codepen rss feed for my website. I am having small issue limiting the results.

Currently displays over 10 results in the rss feed. But I would like to know the best way to limit results to 5

Question: How could I limit the results of my rss feed to 5 only.

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/mVMEmO)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    url = 'http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/public/feed/';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
        },
        success: function(xml){
            var postlist = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
            var html = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
            $.each(postlist, function(idx, data) {

                html += '<li>';
                html += '<h3 class="codepen_feed_title">' + data.title + '</h3>';
                html += '<a href="' + data.link + '" target="_blank">';           
                html += '<span class="codepen_feed_content">Click Here To View It!</div>';
                html += '</a>';
                html += '</li>';
            });
            html += '</ul>';
            $(".codepen_feed").append(html);
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I've removed the tag `codepen` that you created, not because it's inherently a bad tag, but because I feel it would be often misused by the less experienced users of Stack Overflow, to tag questions that include codepen examples, rather than to tag questions about the codepen API and service itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a return value for your each loop

```
$.each(postlist, function(idx, data) {
       var title = data.title;

       html += '<li>';
       html += '<h3 class="codepen_feed_title">' + data.title + '</h3>';
       html += '<a href="' + data.link + '" target="_blank">';           
       html += '<span class="codepen_feed_content">Click Here To View It!</div>';
       html += '</a>';
       html += '</li>';
       return idx < 4;
 });
```